# Merge isn't working when trying to get data using time as main coulm

Tags: python, merge

I would be grateful if anyone could help. I have 2 data frame and  need to merge them with certain column but it does not work

I need to merge (Today_Shift) located in DF ( PG ) with ( Start Time EGS ) located in DF ( Cap ) to get column ( Capped SCH Shift )

**Desire Output **

```
       Today-Shift  Capped SCH Shift
0         0.375      09:00
1         0.375      09:00
2      0.291667      07:30
3      0.291667      07:30
4      0.291667      07:30
```

## First Data Frame ( Cap)

```
  Start Time EGS Start Time UAE  Int no. Status End Time UAE  \
0       07:00:00       09:00:00        1      N     18:00:00   
1       07:30:00       09:30:00        2      N     18:30:00   
2       08:00:00       10:00:00        3      N     19:00:00   
3       08:30:00       10:30:00        4      N     19:30:00   
4       09:00:00       11:00:00        5      N     20:00:00   

   Capped Next Day SCh  Capped SCH Shift  
0                  0.0               9.0  
1                  0.0               9.0  
2                  0.0               9.0  
3                  0.0               9.0  
4                  0.0               9.0
```

## Second Data Frame ( PG)

```
       Today-Shift
0         0.375
1         0.375
2      0.291667
3      0.291667
4      0.291667
```

I have placed code below and the error as well.

**Code**

```
PG = pd.merge(PG,Cap[['Today-Shift','Capped SCH Shift']],how='left' ,suffixes=('', '_remove'))
PG.drop([i for i in PG.columns if 'remove' in i],axis=1, inplace=True)
```

**Error**

```
KeyError: "['Today-Shift'] not in index"
```

Comment: I think the data frame cap has no column name Today-shift.

Comment: Could you please add a (sample of your) expected output. There are lots of ways to merge dfs. It's not clear which particular variant you have in mind as the end result.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback , i have added the output desire , for the merge i need to add column with the ( Capped SCH Shift ) beside column ( Today-Shift ) in PG Data frame

Comment: Thanks for the update. Still not sure though. Your column `Today-Shift` contains excel decimal representations of time: 2x `09:00` followed by 3x `07:00`. What logic is leading you to 2x `09:00` followed by 3x `07:30` (!) for `Capped SCH Shift`? In `df_cap` the column `Capped SCH Shift` only contains the value `9.0` to begin with.